# Do I need to get GMS for google MlKit?

Tags: java, android

Iam developing an application that uses google mlkit . Now I want to make that as a system app in a device but I do not have GMS certification for this device Is it possible  to run that application as a system application without GMS?

Answer (score 0):

For installing the application as a system app you need a rooted device and there are also some 3rd party apps available to install user apps as system apps by using such apps as Titanium Backup, but you have to go for the paid version of the app to be able to enjoy such feature, for other methods you can check :

- https://www.androidauthority.com/install-user-app-as-system-app-how-to-93522/
- https://www.isunshare.com/android/2-ways-to-convert-user-app-to-system-app.html

Comment: I have a rooted device ...but this device is not subjected to GMS .Am not using GMS services like youtube playstore etc(which i do not need) I have developed a application to recognize face that uses google mlkit API...So if i want to make that application as system app do I need gms?

Comment: GMS is a collection of google applications(Gmail,Gmap,Playstore,etc) and application programming interfaces (APIs) services from Google. GMS is used by manufacturers of Android devices as pre-installed apps like(Samsung,Vivo,etc), for smartphones, tablets, and smart TVs. GMS are the Android Applications developed by Google for manufacturers of Android that often come pre−installed on Android devices. You can't have GMS in your app